# C# UWP how to trigger a method every interval?

Tags: c#, uwp, timer

I am currently trying to animate a timer that shows how long the app has been running.

```
_timerThread = new Thread(_textBlockTimer.CounterStart);
_timerThread.IsBackground = true;
_timerThread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
_timerThread.Start();
```

The Timer class looks like this:

```
class Timer {
    private TextBlock _timeTextBlock;
    private bool _timing = false;
    private int _timer = 0;
    public Timer(TextBlock timeTextBlock) {
        _timeTextBlock = timeTextBlock;

    }

    public void CounterStart() {
        _timing = true;
        while (_timing) {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            int time = _timer++;
            _timerTextBlock.Text = time.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Upon performing this, I get the following error:

*System.Exception: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'*

It suggests to me that it might be possible to make this task be part of the same interface?

Is there another way to simply run a method without pausing everything to wait for the method to be done? This won't happen in this case as it's supposed to continuously count upwards.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'

The problem is you update the interface in non-uithread, for trigger a method every interval in UWP we suggest your use [`DispatcherTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer?view=winrt-22000) to replace.

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
timer.Start();


int _timer = 0;
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    int time = _timer++;
    _timeTextBlock.Text = time.ToString();
}
```